# Android. Robolectric. Testing AccountManager results

Tags: junit, mockito, robolectric, android-testing

In my application I use method with account manager for getting owner emails. How I can test this method with Robolectric? Should I use for this purpose mocking? If I'm right, can I use Mockito? Is any tutorials how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

First I implemented the unit test

```
// Imports are skipped
/**
 * Created by fminatchy on 25/02/14.
 */
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
public class TestAuthorization {

    AccountManager accountManager;

    Account account0;
    Account account1;
    Account account2;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        creationComptes();
        accountManager = AccountManager.get(Robolectric.application);
        shadowOf(accountManager).addAccount(account0);
        shadowOf(accountManager).addAccount(account1);
        shadowOf(accountManager).addAccount(account2);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_comptes() {
       final AlbumsActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(AlbumsActivity.class).create().get();

       final String[] accountsName = activity.getGoogleAccounts();
       assertThat(Arrays.asList(accountsName)).containsExactly("compte n°1", "compte n°3");


    }

    private void creationComptes() {
        account0 = new Account("compte n°1", GoogleAccountManager.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        account1 = new Account("compte n°2", "pas google");
        account2 = new Account("compte n°3", GoogleAccountManager.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    }
```

and their is the code located in the activity :

```
  public String[] getGoogleAccounts() {
        final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this.getApplicationContext());
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(GoogleAccountManager.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        String[] names = new String[accounts.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            names[i] = accounts[i].name;
        }
        return names;
    }
```